# Can't specify multiple source paths for JDT Compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm currently having issues with the usage of the [JDT Batch Compiler](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm). My issue relates to specifying the sourcepath in the command outlined in the link I posted above. I'm able to specify one sourcepath, but not multiple ones. Let me explain in a short example:

Suppose I have two same-level folders `dir1` and `dir2`, and both have a `src` folder. Let's assume I'm currently in `dir1` in my command prompt. Also assume I want to print warnings for invalid Javadoc. If I run the following:

```
java -jar ecj.jar -classpath -sourcepath ./src -warn:+javadoc -1.5
```

I'm given the intended warnings (with some classpath errors). However, if I specify two `src` folders, like such:

```
java -jar ecj.jar -classpath -sourcepath ./src;../dir2/src -warn:+javadoc -1.5
```

I'm given the following error:

```
Unrecognized option : .\src;..\dir2\src
```

The JDT compiler documentation states I should be able to specify multiple `src` folders by separating them with a semi-colon. Why is it not working the way I intended?

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same issue and had a look at the respective source code at https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core. The simple and unfortunate answer is: the code is broken and does not work as [documented](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_batch_compiler.htm). The error is thrown [here](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core/blob/babeca48101828a5e0f0b65ec684699efb4bc8e5/org.eclipse.jdt.core/batch/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/batch/Main.java#L2974). The command line parser simply does not handle/parse multiple source paths separated by semicolons.

While you cannot use multiple paths with `-sourcepath` like:

```
java -jar ecj.jar -sourcepath ./src;../dir2/src
```

What worked for me was to simply specify both directories separately as last arguments specifying the `-sourcepath` option:

```
java -jar ecj.jar ./src ../dir2/src
```